# This code works in debug mode but not in release mode c++

Tags: c++, release, primes

I am trying to generate prime numbers up to 1 billion. This code works fine in debug mode but in release mode it crashes after 2 3. Anyone able to help here?

```
void SieveOfEratosthenes(size_t n)
{

// Create a boolean array "prime[0..n]" and initialize
// all entries it as true. A value in prime[i] will
// finally be false if i is Not a prime, else true.
bool* prime = new bool[1000000000];

memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));

for (size_t p = 2; p*p <= n; p++)
{
    // If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime
    if (prime[p] == true)
    {
        // Update all multiples of p
        for (size_t i = p * 2; i <= n; i += p)
            prime[i] = false;
    }
}

// Prsize_t all prime numbers
for (size_t p = 2; p <= n; p++)
    if (prime[p])
        cout << p << " ";
}

int main()
{
size_t n = 1000000000;
cout << "Following are the prime numbers smaller "
    << " than or equal to " << n << endl;
SieveOfEratosthenes(n);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? What is the error? See [ask] for details on how to ask a good question.

Comment: `memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));` does not do what you think it does and makes your code an unidiomatic mess. You should read a good C++ book.

Comment: Instead of fiddling with C functions, you could use `std::vector<bool> prime(n, true);` and get it initialized in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that the `memset` call is wrong. You need to call it as `memset(prime, true, sizeof(bool) * 1000000)`. `sizeof(prime)` will return `8`, which is the most likely size of a pointer on the computer you're testing this.

Comment: Whether or not this works depends on the implementation and even where it does work, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

There are two main problems here.

First, this is incorrect:

```
memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
```

The expression `sizeof(prime)` gives you the size of the *pointer* (most likely 4 or 8), not what it points to.  So you're only setting 4 or 8 bytes.  You could do it this way:

```
memset(prime, true, sizeof(*prime) * n`);
```

However that depends on `sizeof(*prime)` being 1.  If it's not, the values won't be what you expect.  The proper way of doing this is:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    prime[i] = true;
}
```

The other issue is the limits in your `for` loops:

```
for (size_t p = 2; p*p <= n; p++)
...
for (size_t i = p * 2; i <= n; i += p)
...
for (size_t p = 2; p <= n; p++)
```

In each of these, you're checking if the loop counter, which you use as an array index, is `<= n`.  Since your array has `n` elements, the valid indexes in this array go from 0 to `n-1`.  And because you don't exit the loop when the index is `n`,  you end up reading / writing past the end of the array.  This invokes undefined behavior.

You need to change these loop conditions to `< n`:

```
for (size_t p = 2; p*p < n; p++)
...
for (size_t i = p * 2; i < n; i += p)
...
for (size_t p = 2; p < n; p++)
```

Also, at the end of your `SieveOfEratosthenes` be sure to `delete[] prime;` so you don't leak memory.

Comment: Whether or not this works depends on the implementation and even where it does work, it's not a good idea. Please teach beginners proper good practice instead of "fixing" their poor trial-and-error results.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Updated to initialize the array properly.

Comment: With the loop, the answer is technically correct, but still endorses bad practice. If you choose to answer questions like this, at least do it right and teach them how to properly use containers instead of that 90s style memory management.

Comment: For this, a `std::vector<bool> prime(1000000000);`, even with the drawbacks of `std::vector<bool>`, would have sufficed.